# SwiftUI why do I need an identifiable in a ForEach loop?

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I have some VStack and I loop over some array of emojis in it with a ForEach it requires an ID, why is this the case? If it's literally just looping over the elements of the array why does it need an ID? Like there's the first element v[0], second element v[1] and etc why is an identifiable required?

Comment: Because that's how SwiftUI tells the elements apart. For example, consider the case that [0] and [1] switch positions. For an animation, one would want to know that they actually switched and not that it was just brand new elements in those spots.

Comment: Watch Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21

Answer (score 1):

Because if it used the index then it wouldn't know that the view at [0] moved to [1] so wouldn't be able to animate changes. If you aren't moving, adding or deleting then you can simply use `ForEach(0..<5) { index in`